# Long SSRS URL Works in IE and Edge, but not Chrome (The report server encountered an unhandled exception in HttpApplication.)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

EDIT:  Figured it out.

1. Go to the server where SSRS is installed.
2. Locate the installation directory for SSRS (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer in my case)
3. Edit the httpRunTime property of the web.config file to include the line maxQueryStringLength="5120"  (or some number greater than the length of the string I am trying to pass)
4. Save
5. Stop and Start the SQL Server Reporting Services service.

### Original Question Below

We have some Tableau dashboards that my clients use via Tableau public.  This cannot be secured, so we are constructing SSRS report URLs from the filter selections the user makes and going over to SSRS.  There seems to be some kind of character limit issue in Chrome.  I'm not sure what it is, but when passing a very long URL (4000+ characters), an error occurs in Chrome, but not IE or Edge.

EDIT:  Seems to cut out at 2114 characters.  At 2115 characters, the error shows.

EDIT2:  Here's what the SSRS logs say: System.Web.HttpException: The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value.

The report server encountered an unhandled exception in HttpApplication.

Does anyone know why this happens?

The URL is below.

http://oirtest.host.ualr.edu/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Development/Blane%20Dev/tableau_integration_test_2&pParamCSV=2018||Arts%2C%20Letters%2C%20and%20Sciences~Business~Clinton%20School%20of%20Public%20Services~Donaghey%20Engr%20%26%20Info%20Tech~Education%20%26%20%20Health%20Professions~Interdisciplinary%20Studies~Law~Social%20Sciences%20%26%20Communications||Accounting~Applied%20Communication~Applied%20Science~Art%20and%20Design~Audiology%20and%20Speech%20Pathology~Biology~Business%20Administration~Business%20Information%20Systems~Chemistry~Clinton%20School%20of%20Public%20Service~College%20of%20Social%20Sciences%20and%20Communication~Computer%20Science~Construction%20Management%20and%20Civil%20and%20Construction%20Engineering~Counseling%2C%20Human%20Performance%20and%20Rehabilitation~Criminal%20Justice~Earth%20Sciences~Economics%20and%20Finance~Education~Engineering%20Technology~English~History~Information%20Science~Interdisciplinary%20Studies~Law~Management~Marketing%20and%20Advertising~Mass%20Communications~Mathematics%20and%20Statistics~Music~Nursing~Philosophy%20%26%20Interdisciplinary%20Studies%20Department~Physics%20and%20Astronomy~Psychology~Public%20Affairs~Rhetoric%20and%20Writing~Social%20Work~Sociology%20and%20Anthropology~Systems%20Engineering~Theatre%20Arts%20and%20Dance~World%20Languages||Accounting~Adult%20and%20Professional%20Learning~American%20Sign%20Language%20Studies~Anthropology~Applied%20Communication%20Studies~Applied%20Psychology~Applied%20Science~Applied%20Sciences~Applied%20Statistics~Art~Bioinformatics~Biology~Building%20Level%20Administration~Business~Business%20Administration~Business%20Analytics~Business%20Information%20Systems~Certificate%20in%20Accounting~Chemistry~Civil%20%26%20Construction%20Engineering~Communication%20Sciences%20%26%20Disorders~Computer%20and%20Information%20Sciences~Computer%20Programming~Computer%20Science~Conflict%20Mediation~Construction%20Management~Construction%20Science~Counselor%20Education~Crime%20Scene%20Investigation~Criminal%20Justice~Curriculum%20%26%20Instruction~Curriculum%2FProgram%20Administration%20%26%20Supervision~Dance%20Performance~Data%20Science~Dyslexia%20Therapist~E-Commerce~Early%20Childhood%20Education~Economics~Education~Educational%20Administration~Electrical%20and%20Computer%20Systems%20Engineering~Electronics%20%26%20Computer%20Engineering%20Technology~Elementary%20Education~Engineering%20Science%20%26%20Systems~Engineering%20Technology%20(Mechanical)~English~Environmental%20Health%20Sciences~Finance~General%20Education~Geology~Gerontology~Gifted%20Education~Gifted%2C%20Creative%2C%20and%20Talented%20Education~Health%20Education%2FPromotion~Health%2C%20Human%20Performance%20%26%20Sport%20Management~Higher%20Education~History~Human%20Resources%20and%20Organizational%20Psychology~Information%20Quality~Information%20Science~Interdisciplinary%20Studies~International%20Business~International%20Studies~Interpretation%3A%20%20American%20Sign%20Language%2FEnglish~K-12%20Health%20and%20Physical%20Education~Law~Law%20Enforcement~Learning%20Systems%20Technology~Literacy%20Intervention%20Specialist~Management~Marketing~Mass%20Communication~Master%20of%20Public%20Administration%20(4%2B1)%20Program~Mathematical%20Sciences~Mathematics~Mechanical%20Engineering%20Technology~Mechanical%20Systems%20Engineering~Middle%20Childhood%20Education~Music~Music%20Education~Nonprofit%20Management~Nursing~Nursing%20Completion%20Program~Online%20Writing%20Instruction~Orientation%20%26%20Mobility%20of%20the%20Blind~Performance~Philosophy~Physics~Political%20Science~Professional%20%26%20Technical%20Writing~Professional%20Sales~Psychology~Public%20History~Public%20Service~Reading~Reading%2FLiteracy%20Coach~Rehabilitation%20Counseling~Rehabilitation%20of%20the%20Blind~Rural%20and%20Urban%20School%20Leadership~Social%20Work~Sociology~Special%20Education~Special%20Education%20K-12~Sport%20Management~Superintendency~Systems%20Engineering~Technology%20Innovation~Theatre%20Arts~User%20Experience%20Design%20%26%20Web%2FMobile%20Development~Web%20Design%20%26%20Development~Workplace%20Spanish~World%20Languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to the server where SSRS is installed.
2. Locate the installation directory for SSRS (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer in my case)
3. Edit the httpRunTime property of the web.config file to include the line maxQueryStringLength="5120" (or some number greater than the length of the string I am trying to pass)
4. Save
5. Stop and Start the SQL Server Reporting Services service.